# Drawer edges in App layout of the angular component with Angular Dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-components

Drawer edges in App layout of the angular component with AngularDart don't draw while `scrolling` content at `material-content`, how can I fix this? [image]

app_component.html

```
<material-drawer persistent #drawer="drawer" [attr.end]="end ? '' : null">
<material-list *deferredContent>
    <div group class="mat-drawer-spacer"></div>
    <div group>
        <material-list-item>
            <material-icon icon="inbox"></material-icon>Inbox
        </material-list-item>
        <material-list-item>
            <material-icon icon="star"></material-icon>Star
        </material-list-item>
        <material-list-item>
            <material-icon icon="send"></material-icon>Sent Mail
        </material-list-item>
        <material-list-item>
            <material-icon icon="drafts"></material-icon>Drafts
        </material-list-item>
    </div>
    <div group>
        <div label>Tags</div>
        <material-list-item>
            <material-icon icon="star"></material-icon>Favorites
        </material-list-item>
    </div>
 </material-list>
</material-drawer>
<material-content>
    <header class="material-header shadow">
        <div class="material-header-row">
            <material-button icon
                         class="material-drawer-button"(trigger)="drawer.toggle()">
            <material-icon icon="menu"></material-icon>
        </material-button>
        <span class="material-header-title">Simple Layout</span>
        <div class="material-spacer"></div>
        <nav class="material-navigation">
            <a href="#AppLayout">Link 1</a>
        </nav>
        <nav class="material-navigation">
            <a href="#AppLayout">Link 2</a>
        </nav>
        <nav class="material-navigation">
            <a href="#AppLayout">Link 3</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="content-test">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <h3>Options</h3>
       <material-toggle [(checked)]="end" label="end">
        </material-toggle>
    </div>
</material-content>
```

app_component.dart

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';

@Component(
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
    styleUrls: const [
    'app_component.css',
    'package:angular_components/src/components/app_layout/layout.scss.css'],
    directives: const [
      DeferredContentDirective,
      MaterialButtonComponent,
      MaterialIconComponent,
      MaterialPersistentDrawerDirective,
      MaterialToggleComponent,
      MaterialListComponent,
      MaterialListItemComponent,
    ],
    providers: const [materialProviders],
    )
class AppComponent {
  bool end = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this is by allowing the main-content to scroll independently like so:

```
material-content {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Produces this:

[image]